# Use case diagram for e-learning analytics correctness

Tags: uml, use-case

I would like to draw a use case diagram following those rules:

1. Check the number of contributions per person
2. Check the density of contributions by group
3. Check the density of words used in the contribution posts
4. Print the results
5. The developer develop the application.
6. The skateholders must be logged.
7. All the Use cases happen on the E-learning forum.

Of course skateholders will access data according to the associated privilege level granted to them as student, teacher, or manager.

I have some questions about my uses:

a. is the uml diagram right?
b. with such a context is it possible to avoid lines crossing one another?
c. any suggestion?

Thank you.

This diagram is drawn with Visual paradigm 12.1, standard edition.[image]

**Edit**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few remarks:

- `login` is not a use case at all. Remove it.
- I would not picture `print` as use case (where you forgot to add `<<extends>>` to the relation). It's pretty pointless and will not be something you have in common or can see as added value. It will simply be part of the flow of events of the single `Check` use cases. So remove it as well.
- Use cases are better placed on the border of the system under consideration rather than inside since they describe so to say the interface.
- To avoid crossing you can create multiple diagrams. One per actor with the focus on which UC he's using, one per UC to see which actors and requirements are related.

Comment: Thanks Kilian for your comment. Should I leave the developer actor as that without any relationship?

Comment: If it does not have a use case it would be rather pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: I have edited and updated the use case diagram with the same requirements. Is that correct now? Is the developer use case meaningful?

Comment: You missed my first point: `login` is no use case. Remove it! `Develop...` seems to be a quite complex use case. I guess it's wrong somehow. Hard to tell without knowing the domain. The include is the wrong way around. Please look for Bittner/Spence on Amazon and read it.

Comment: Thank you Kilian for your comments.